# Is my TextOverflow.ellipsis causing my text to be moved to the right?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm displaying text in a ListView.Builder and if some of the text is too long I'm using the overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis property of the Text widget to ensure it doesn't cause an overflow error. Well when text is too long, it uses the TextOverflow correctly, but it also shifts the text to the right. I want to keep the text all aligned. Could this be caused by the TextOverflow or is this a layout issue?

This is an image of one of the pieces of text that had ellipsis used on it due to it being too long. As you can see it is shifted to the right. This only occurs when an ellipsis is used though. If the Text doesn't need an ellipsis it doesn't get shifted to the right.

[image: Ellipsis issue image]

This is the code that renders this entire page. The bit that I's being moved to the right is where the the text displays mileage[index].trippurpose  I've included the entire code incase it is a layout issue that I keep overlooking.

```
Container(
                          height: 60,
                          child: Row(
                            children: <Widget>[
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Container(
                                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 5, top: 13),
                                      child: Text(mileage[index].tripdate,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black),
                                          textAlign: TextAlign.left),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 3,
                                child: Column(
                                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                        padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 13, left: 10),
                                        child: Text(mileage[index].trippurpose,
                                                style: TextStyle(
                                                    fontSize: 15,
                                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                                    color: Colors.black,
                                                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat'),
                                                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                                softWrap: true,
                                                textAlign: TextAlign.center),),

                                    Padding(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                                      child: Row(
                                        children: [Text(
                                          '${mileage[index].tripfrom} - ',
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              color: Colors.black,
                                              fontStyle: FontStyle.italic),
                                        ),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
                                            child:Text(
                                              mileage[index].tripto,
                                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                              softWrap: false,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.black,
                                                  fontStyle: FontStyle.italic
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                  children: [
                                    Padding(
                                      padding:
                                      EdgeInsets.only(top: 13, right: 10),
                                      child: Container(
                                        child: Text(
                                            mileage[index].triptotalmiles,
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 16,
                                                color: Colors.black),
                                            textAlign: TextAlign.right),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),)
                            ],
                          ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code, you can use to create design as per your code.

```
Container(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Text(
                'THIS IS A TEST TEXT',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 3,
              fit: FlexFit.tight,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    'THIS IS A TEST TEXT',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                  Text(
                    'THIS IS A TEST TEXT',
                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 1,
              child: Text(
                'THIS IS A TEST TEXT',
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      )
```

Note :- You are applying wrong logics to your code. flex is best fit with Flexible widget. Also check FlexFit.tight.